# android how to apply style to subview in xml

Tags: android

I have the following view hierachy:

```
<CardView>
  <TextView />
  <ImageView />
</CardView>
```

I need 2 types of `cards`, one with smaller `TextView`s and another with larger `TextView`s. I want to create 2 `card` styles and apply them for different use cases. How can I do that? 
Note that I need to apply styles to subview (i.e. `text view`), not card view itself

Answer (score 1):

The basic way that style works is so:

The `styles.xml` file in `res/values`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomText" parent="@style/Text">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#008</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and in your `TextView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    style="@style/CustomText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello, World!" />
```

So you'll want to create CustomText1 and CustomText2 and apply them to the proper TextViews.

If you need to apply styles to child views, you can apply them as a theme. From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html):

> When you apply a style to a single View in the layout, the attributes
>   defined by the style are applied only to that View. If a style is
>   applied to a ViewGroup, the child View elements don't inherit the
>   style attributes; only the element to which you directly apply the
>   style applies its attributes. However, you can apply a style so that
>   it applies to all View elements—by applying the style as a theme.

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear. I want 2 cards, each with different text views.

Comment: baiscally i need to style the cards to use different text view style

Comment: If you want to apply a style that gets copied to its children, you need to apply the style as a theme, but it is applied to the view and all child elements

Comment: no i just need to style a specific `text view` inside `card`

Comment: It's this line: `style="@style/CustomText"` in your `TextView`

Comment: But you need to create the `CustomText` style in your `styles.xml` file

Comment: i need to pass the style from card to text view

Comment: because when implementing the card, the font size is unknown

Comment: no you misunderstood my question. I know how to apply styles (everyone knows), but i need to apply style to subviews

Comment: My first comment is in regard to child views. You need to apply them as a theme.